# Resources for lattice QCD phase diagram

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, phase-transition, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-gauge-theory

I have done some research on lattice QCD spectroscopy, I am familiar with numerical simulations to the point of effectively using the asymptotic behaviour of 2-point functions to recunstruct the spectrum of the theory. The point is that nothing of what I have done in lattice QFT to this point has ever required me to use my statistical mechanics knowledge beyond the really basic level of knowing what a partition funcion is.

I have seen that there is a lot of interest in using lattice methods to study the deconfinement transition of QCD, and I am interested in undesstanding it, for personal curiosity and also to widen my scope as a researcher, but I have a fairly marked High energy Background with little to no previous knowledge of StatMech beyond an undergraduate level.

Can you guys recommend some kind of "to-read" list to be able to understand this area of physics? Where should I start? I know about ensembles and partition functions, I know about computing expectation values from functional integrals but, for example, I know little to nothing about phase transitions or correlation lenghts.